# No free space after installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk-usage

I have experimented with Linux distros in the past, but now I want to work on a Linux OS permanently. I dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Before installing Ubuntu, I created a partition to install them later and created an extra disk (named `:L` for Linux) (photo 1). I gave Ubuntu 400GB of space and Windows 600GB (1TB HDD).

I installed Ubuntu on the partition with the 400GB space, but when I tried to make an update Ubuntu, it said that I don't have any free space available in the 400GB disk. I searched and tried different things, but I got no results. I tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` (photo 2) and `-du /home/* -sh/` (photo 3). What can I do to bring those GBs in the game? Maybe it was a bad idea to create a partition and create a new disk (:L)?

Photo 1:

[image]

Photo 2:

[image]

Photo 3:

[image]

Comment: You can use disk partition tools in Windows (use `diskpart` in `cmd` or disk management tool) or (g)parted tools in Linux to check what's going on with your disks. Use `sudo parted -l` or install gparted and use `sudo gparted`.
It's otherwise normal that you cannot use a disk with linux partition in windows.

Comment: This doesn't help much, and I don't know Greek. From Ubuntu what does `sudo parted -l` show? And from Win10, what does `diskmgmt.msc` show?

Comment: Disk Management on Windows: http://prntscr.com/rxcwby
Sudo parted -l on Ubuntu: http://prntscr.com/rxcyvy
A message it showed me when i started Ubuntu 10 minutes ago: http://prntscr.com/rxczad
At sudo parted -l you can see 4 partitions. The 3 of them with numbers 1,2,4 were partitions before and number 3 is the partition i made to install Ubuntu.
I don't want to work on Ubuntu partition via Windows,my problem is that working in Ubuntu,it seems that i don't have space left. Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't created any new disk. There is only one disk shown. Perhaps you meant *Drive*. According to Win10 it's unformatted, hence described as 'Raw'. You should not have given sda3 a letter. That applies to NTFS partitions. I suggest go to Live Ubuntu, delete sda3, then re-install Ubuntu in the unallocated space with ext4 format.

Comment: Wrong word for the "disk". I imagined that would be a problem. Thank you very much. I will inform you again.

Comment: Hello again. I deleted the volume and reinstalled Ubuntu and now everything is ok. I made an update but still i can not connect to the wi-fi. Sometimes it doesn't find any network and when it does,it doesn't connect. I found a video suggesting installing rtlwifi with other commands. I did it,it connected after i did everything but now i have the same problem. Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: @Geolek You need to raise a separate question re wi-fi. You need to give details of wi-fi card and show output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `sudo rfkill list all` to start with.